# How to reference a .cs file from main .asmx file when running a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I've just started experimenting with C#/.NET and for my first project I'm creating a webservice.

I followed this [very brief tutorial](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/writing_a_webservice/) (mono-project.org), and can connect successfully via my browser after running `xsp4` from the command-line.

My question - how do I import a `.cs` file containing a namespace + several class definitions from my main `.asmx` file? When I run `xsp4`, it does't take any command-line arguments unlike the `mono-csc` compiler in which you tell which files you want to compile into the final output.

When I try to reference a class (prefixed by its namespace) defined in one of these `.cs` files, it simply tells me that the namespace cannot be found.

Here's some simple code:

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" Class="MathService.MathService" %>

using System;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Collections.Generic;

using com.example;

namespace MathService
{
    [WebService (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/NumberService")]
    public class MathService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int AddNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int SubtractNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 - number2;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public com.example.Response GetBalance(com.example.Request request)
        {
            com.example.Response response = new com.example.Response();
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you see the part about "This page is likely outdated (last edited on 16 Nov 2007)"? You should be using [WCF](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/web/wcf/) for new web service development.

Comment: I did notice that - however that was the newest version of that page available. Thanks for the WCF tip.

Answer (score 2):

You mean, the `@import`? Should be at the very first lines of your page:

```
<%@ Import namespace="MyAssembly.MyUnit" %>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eb44kack(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: It is not different, it is the same. But you are using the `.asmx` extension. This means you are writing a page-script like code. You could implement your WS in a code behind file, then it would be a `.asmx.cs` and then you would use a `using` statement.

Comment: "using" is just fine, since it's in the body of the code.